# Can't get current time forecast using forecast.io API

Tags: java, android

I'm building a mega simple weather Android app using the forecast.io service.

Using the default call of

```
https://api.forecast.io/forecast/<my_key>/37.8136,144.9631?units=auto
```

Always seems to give me the forecast at a time that I don't care for - ie, its currently 2.40PM here, and it keeps giving me 3.40AM forecast.

So I then try to use the time param and yet it still gives me 3.40AM, not 2.40PM

```
https://api.forecast.io/forecast/<my_key>/37.8136,144.9631,1451619638?units=auto
```

I've validated `1451619638` as my current unix time via the helpful site http://www.epochconverter.com/

Any pointers as to why I can't seem to get MY local current time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API returns the timezone and then the offset from GMT. Check those.

The idea of the first one is if you do not provide the time, you will get a current forecast, and all you will have to do is convert it into your timezone. So if they are doing GMT and you are GMT - 8, you simply subtract 8 from the time value.

Both fields are there:

```
latitude: The requested latitude.
longitude: The requested longitude.
timezone: The IANA timezone name for the requested location (e.g. America/New_York). This is the timezone used for text forecast summaries and for determining the exact start time of daily data points. (Developers are advised to rely on local system settings rather than this value if at all possible: users may deliberately set an unusual timezone, and furthermore are likely to know what they actually want better than our timezone database does.)
offset: The current timezone offset in hours from GMT.
```

I have been using this API for a while.

Comment: I see what you are saying, but it still doesn't make sense because, for example right now here it is over 20 degrees celcius, but the first call, with no time, is giving me 6 degrees

Comment: And you are positive that your coordinates are not wrong. Think about it: how can it make any sense that it would have the temperature wrong for a specific point on the globe? It's not shifting the time. If you don't provide the time, it's going to use now.

Comment: Fair enough, I thought about that - but I am in Melbourne and I simply googled Melbourne lattitude/longitude and the above URL params is what I got ?

Comment: Haha, ok that's for sure wrong. Dude, you are at -37º latitude.

Comment: HAHA wtf, thanks man, that seems to fix it - stupid Google :D

Comment: Sure. Maps and time are a lot of fun. Have made a million mistakes like that.

Comment: oh I think i see - Google says its "S" , for South I guess which means i should be smart enough to add the -  :) Cheers